# How to remove the last comma in for loop

Tags: php

```
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

for( $x=1 ; $x<=10 ; $x++){
echo "$x".",";
}
?>
</body>
</html>`
```

1.output =1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,

2. i have this output. how can i remove the last comma? your help is needed.

Comment: I see over 3000 posts on this site when I search for [remove last comma](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+last+comma). This is a fairly common programming issue which should be easy to track down with some searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
for( $x=1 ; $x<=10 ; $x++){
echo "$x";
if($x!=10)
echo ",";
}
?>
```

Check for the last iteration and avoid ','

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: sorry sir if i ask. if    $str = ' ';

for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $i ;    
 if ($i!=10)
 $str="-";
}

echo $str;    i want to have the result 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 but at the end i have this -10 answer. because i need to declare loop is a variable. can u help me sir? im doin my FYP in degree but still doesnt have idea how to create website like google form. that allowed user to create their own survey.

Comment: <?php

 $str = '';
 for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ )
 {
 $str .= $i ;
 if ($i!=10)
 $str.="-";
 }
 echo $str;

Comment: thank very much sir. may god bless you sir. sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the last comma using [join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php).

```
echo join(',', range(1,10));
```